# Prove by induction that for $n\geq1$, $(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)/n \geq (a_1*a_2*...*a_n)^{1/n}$

Tags: induction

Prove by induction that for $n\geq1$, $(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)/n \geq (a_1*a_2*...*a_n)^{1/n}.$ I proved the base case, not sure how to do the inductive step. The values of the sequence are greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: It's the AM/GM inequality.

Comment: This is the AM-GM (Arithmetic Mean -- Geometric Mean) inequality. There are plenty of sites in internet with the proof.